# Custom Region Empty

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I have created a custom region in my bootstrap sub-theme. The line in my .info file is:

```
regions[conent_bottom]  = 'Content bottom'
```

I have then added that to my page.tpl.php file using:

```
<?php print render($page['content_bottom']); ?>
```

I have flushed all caches and the new region is showing correctly on the blocks admin page. However, any blocks I allocate to the new region are not showing up on the page.

I have checked the variable for the page using:

```
<?php dpm($page); ?>
```

and the $content_bottom variable is there but is coming up as empty.

Can anyone suggest anything that might be causing this? I'm using Bootstrap 7.x-3.5 with Drupal 7.43.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spelling: regions[conent_bottom]

Comment: Thanks Jaypan for your quick answer, I saw the spelling error and thought that was it, but I corrected it and it made no difference. I have double checked all the spellings now.

Comment: I have also tried adding other custom regions and they all have the same result.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after making the change? Also, you'll need to re-add any blocks to that region, as they would have been assigned to the region conent_bottom which no longer exists.

Comment: Have you assigned any block from admin to the region?

Comment: Thank you Jaypan, after I re-assigned the block as you suggested it all worked. Many thanks for your help :)